Systematic way to fix/seal, identify and confirm the non-obvious cracks/gaps decreasing tightness and causing drafts in an old house
I have a 100 year old house. I do not know about any obvious gaps/cracks/drafts. But generally I feel the house is not very tight. It is very hard to heat up and looses heat quickly (*). It is recommended to use a lighter but walking around the house I do not see obvious difference in the flame. Even if I put it to where I believe a small crack is. On the other hand, since I hear about even sealing receptacles and light switch boxes, it seems even tiny gaps count and can add up.

Is there any better/accurate way to identify even small and tiny cracks?
Is this something that should be done when the temperature differential is maximized (i.e., in winter)?
How can I systematically walk in the house and crawl in the crawlspace and attic to identify & seal gaps/holes/cracks?
Is there a way to verify they have been filled properly/things even make a difference?
For receptacles, light switches and lamps, what is the right way to seal?

(*) This can be caused by insulation and drafts and it's likely a combo. While some walls do not have insulation at all (stucco and original lath & plaster), some walls have been renovated and have at least 70ies insulation. New attic insulation was installed. A small part of the ceiling is directly under the roof so does not have insulation either.

With good insulation, sealing drafts does help.  With poor insulation, sealing drafts does not help much.  Insulation helps to lessen heat escape.  Draft sealing is more for comfort/you do not get a chill.

100 year old house can (and usually does) leak more than enough air to directly affect energy use dramatically, @crip659

The systematic approach is to fit the house with a blower door to pressurize it, then use smoke/mist/dust-puff tracing to see what the air currents are and thus where you can tighten things up. That can also give you a numeric value for how much leakage is occurring overall, which may indicate how much effort you want to go to.
Or you can just air-seal the foundation and the attic, which is usually the fastest and most effective place to start.

See: https://www.energy.gov/energysaver/blower-door-tests and https://www.bobvila.com/articles/blower-door-tests/ and https://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/article/passing-a-blower-door-test for more background on Blower Door Tests.

Thanks, I considered blower test but it's expensive and I am afraid that I just get the total number but no conclusion as to where exactly the leaks are. I asked for a sample report but that one only listed some trivial examples (light cans, attic hatch)  and the total reading (CFM50) and effective leakage area.

The unsystematic approach is to hit the usual issues: air-seal foundation and attic, caulk and weather strip windows and doors, consider storm windows/storm doors, ...
